# Error: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-27'

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to do an image uploading in react-native.As i run the app i got this error.Below is the screenshot of the error i got.[image]

Comment: You just need to download SDK for API 27 from the SDK Manager (in Android Studio). The error is for missing platform. Then rebuild the project, it should solve your issue.

Comment: Cool it works .thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you've just imported the project from a new android studio or a new session. 
Try restarting android studio and the download will go without issues.

That's what worked for me.